# DirectX : Nothing is drawn on screen

Tags: c++, debugging, directx

I'm trying to develop a program using DirectX (10) to display on screen.

Thing is, it displays nothing but the color I use to clear the backbuffer.

(I apologize for the quite big chunks of code that follow).

Here is my rendering function :

```
void DXEngine::renderOneFrame()
{
    //First, we clear the back buffer
    m_device->ClearRenderTargetView(m_renderTargetView,D3DXCOLOR(0.0f, 0.125f, 0.3f, 1.0f));

    //Then, we clear the depth buffer
    m_device->ClearDepthStencilView(m_depthStencilView,D3D10_CLEAR_DEPTH,1.0f, 0);

    //Update variables
    m_worldVariable->SetMatrix((float*)&m_world);
    m_viewVariable->SetMatrix((float*)&m_view);
    m_projectionVariable->SetMatrix((float*)&m_projection);

    //Render the cube 
    D3D10_TECHNIQUE_DESC techDesc;
    m_technique->GetDesc(&techDesc);

    for(UINT pass = 0; pass < techDesc.Passes ; pass++){

        m_technique->GetPassByIndex(pass)->Apply(0);
        m_device->DrawIndexed(36,0,0);
    }

    m_swapChain->Present(0,0);
}
```

It is exactly the same as the 5th tutorial on DirectX10 in the DirectX SDK (June 2010) under the "Samples" folder, except it's encapsulated in an object.

My scene is initialized as follow :

```
HRESULT DXEngine::initStaticScene()
{
    HRESULT hr;

    //Vertex buffer creation and initialization
    Vertex1Pos1Col vertices [] = 
    {
        { D3DXVECTOR3( -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f ), D3DXVECTOR4( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ) },
        { D3DXVECTOR3( 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f ), D3DXVECTOR4( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f ) },
        { D3DXVECTOR3( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ), D3DXVECTOR4( 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ) },
        { D3DXVECTOR3( -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ), D3DXVECTOR4( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f ) },
        { D3DXVECTOR3( -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f ), D3DXVECTOR4( 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ) },
        { D3DXVECTOR3( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f ), D3DXVECTOR4( 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f ) },
        { D3DXVECTOR3( 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f ), D3DXVECTOR4( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ) },
        { D3DXVECTOR3( -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f ), D3DXVECTOR4( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f ) },
    };


    D3D10_BUFFER_DESC desc;
    desc.Usage = D3D10_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    desc.ByteWidth = sizeof(Vertex1Pos1Col) * 8;
    desc.BindFlags = D3D10_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    desc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    desc.MiscFlags = 0;

    D3D10_SUBRESOURCE_DATA data;
    data.pSysMem = vertices;
    hr = m_device->CreateBuffer(&desc,&data,&m_vertexBuffer);

    if(FAILED(hr)){
        MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Vertex buffer creation failed"), TEXT("Error"),MB_OK);
        return hr;
    }

    UINT stride = sizeof(Vertex1Pos1Col);
    UINT offset = 0;
    m_device->IASetVertexBuffers(0,1,&m_vertexBuffer,&stride,&offset);

    //Index buffer creation and initialization
    DWORD indices[] = 
    {
        3,1,0,
        2,1,3,

        0,5,4,
        1,5,0,

        3,4,7,
        0,4,3,

        1,6,5,
        2,6,1,

        2,7,6,
        3,7,2,

        6,4,5,
        7,4,6,
    };

    desc.Usage = D3D10_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    desc.ByteWidth = sizeof(DWORD) * 36;
    desc.BindFlags = D3D10_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
    desc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    desc.MiscFlags = 0;
    data.pSysMem = vertices;
    hr = m_device->CreateBuffer(&desc,&data,&m_indexBuffer);

    if(FAILED(hr)){
        MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Index buffer creation failed"), TEXT("Error"),MB_OK);
        return hr;
    }


    m_device->IASetIndexBuffer(m_indexBuffer,DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT,0);

    //Set the primitive topology, i.e. how indices should be interpreted (here, as a triangle list)
    m_device->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D10_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

    D3DXMatrixIdentity(&m_world);

    D3DXVECTOR3 eye(0.0f, 1.0f, -10.0f);
    D3DXVECTOR3 at(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    D3DXVECTOR3 up(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    D3DXMatrixLookAtLH(&m_view, &eye, &at, &up);

    D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(&m_projection, (float)D3DX_PI * 0.25f, m_width/(FLOAT)m_height, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    return hr;
}
```

Once again, it's the exact same code (but encapsulated) as the tutorial I mentionned earlier.

When I open the Tutorial Visual Studio Solution in my IDE, it works and displays nicely what is described in the scene, but when I try to run my "encapsulated" version of this code, nothing shows up but the background color...

Note : My windows message pumps works fine, I can even handle user inputs the way I want, everything's fine. My application performs correctly my engine initialization (I check every single returned error code and there's nothing else but `S_OK` codes).

I have no clue where to search now. I've checked my code times and times again and it's exactly the same as the tutorial, I've checked that everything I encapsulate is set and accessed correctly, etc, but I still can't display anything else than the background color...

I was wondering if anyone here could have an idea of what could possibly cause this, or at least hints on where to look for...

EDIT: Effect file used :

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// File: Tutorial05.fx
//
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Constant Buffer Variables
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
matrix World;
matrix View;
matrix Projection;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct VS_INPUT
{
    float4 Pos : POSITION;
    float4 Color : COLOR;
};

struct PS_INPUT
{
    float4 Pos : SV_POSITION;
    float4 Color : COLOR;
};


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Vertex Shader
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PS_INPUT VS( VS_INPUT input )
{
    PS_INPUT output = (PS_INPUT)0;
    output.Pos = mul( input.Pos, World );
    output.Pos = mul( output.Pos, View );
    output.Pos = mul( output.Pos, Projection );
    output.Color = input.Color;

    return output;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Pixel Shader
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
float4 PS( PS_INPUT input) : SV_Target
{
    return input.Color;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
technique10 Render
{
    pass P0
    {
        SetVertexShader( CompileShader( vs_4_0, VS() ) );
        SetGeometryShader( NULL );
        SetPixelShader( CompileShader( ps_4_0, PS() ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: May be, there is an error in your HLSL shaders (effect)? Can you show it?

Comment: I copied the effect file from the tutorial as well. I'll include it in the post.

Comment: Have you checked if your technique description is correct? Especially if the `for` loop for the passes ist executed at least once. Do you have appropriate blend and depth stencil states? You might want to graphically debug your program. Either with the VS2012 debugger or PIX.

Comment: The for is executed once, according to the number of passes in the technique I provide. And I have the appropriate blend and depth stencil states (I checked that many times). I used the Graphics debugger in VS and found nothing  obviously wrong. I could check that the vertex and index buffers were correct, and that every part of DirectX was set correclty...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, that this can be an error:

Input assembler stage of D3D (10 and 11) pipeline is always waiting for `DXGI_FORMAT_***_UINT` format for index buffers. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) proves this:

> A DXGI_FORMAT that specifies the format of the data in the index
>   buffer. The only formats allowed for index buffer data are 16-bit
>   (DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT) and 32-bit (DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT) integers.

Then look at your code that binds your buffer to IA:

`m_device->IASetIndexBuffer(m_indexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT, 0);`

I think you should use DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT for your case, like this:

`m_device->IASetIndexBuffer(m_indexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);`

Comment: Nailed it. I don't know why I had this in my code, as I followed the SDK tutorial... Thank you !

Comment: Also, I think that directx debug layer should send you a warning when you try to do this binding. Anyway, if you didn't see it - try to find how to setup debug info - it is more than useful.